# Clean up on for loop break

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, iterator, iterable

Can you create an iterable in python which runs clean up code when for loop exits? Something like:

```
from random import randint

class Iterable:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return randint(1, 10)
    def __iterclose__(self):
        print("Clean up code")

for x in Iterable():
    if x < 5:
        break

# Prints "Clean up code"
```

Comment: You are mixing two different concepts Iterables and Iterators. Itterable's `__iter__` should return an Iterator object. While Iterator's `__iter__` should return `self`.

Comment: I know I *could* use a context manager, but it'd be much nicer not to have to!

Comment: @Jack well, you can't always get what you want. So the answer is no. Note, you've defined an *iterator*, note merely an iterable.

Comment: @TomKarzes huh?

Comment: When finishing iteration, you should raise the `StopIteration` exception, at this point you should already know that you have to perform the clean up, else this iterator will run forever.

Comment: You instantiate your iterator before you start the loop (or use walrus in 3.8 if so inclined) and you give it a method you call once out of the loop. Or you instantiate it with known number of iterations and doe the clean-up when done. How else would iterator learn when you're done iterating over it? There is no interface to signal you broke out.

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm not following you, why couldn't it?  `__iterclose__`, presumably, would kill it. I don't see why this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Note, the `__iterclose__` [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0533/#note-on-timing) is currently deferred, but from what I understand, it should work the way you want it when it is implemented

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think you're right about `__iterclose__`.  The case I was thinking of was when you assign an iterator to a variable `x`, then have `for v in x:`, break from it (before the iterator completes), then follow it with another `for v in x:`.  The second loop picks up where the first loop ended.  It seems undesirable to me to call `__iterclose__` in between the two loops when in fact the iterator is to be continued.  It seems likely to break the above case.  I don't think this feature was well thought-out.  The iterator needs to reliably know when it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to benefit from the iterable protocol, you should let your Iterable gain control about the stop condition. How about this:

```py
from random import randint


class Iterable:

    def __init__(self, max):
        self.i = 0
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.i += 1
        if self.i > self.max:
            self.cleanup()
            raise StopIteration
        return randint(1, 10)

    def cleanup(self):
        print("Clean up code")


for x in Iterable(5):
    print(x)
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong or abnormal about an infinite iterator.

Comment: That might be. But given the task at hand: How would you call the cleanup step if it should be done by the iterator?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment :

When finishing iteration, you should raise the `StopIteration` exception, at this point you should already know that you have to perform the clean up, else this iterator will run forever.

Also iterator and iterable are different things, from fluent python book:

> iterator
>
> Any object that implements the **next** no-argument method that
>   returns the next item in a series or raises StopIteration when there
>   are no more items. Python iterators also implement the **iter** method
>   so they are iterable as well

Where:

> iterable Any object from which the iter built-in function can obtain
>   an iterator. Objects implementing an **iter** method returning an
>   iterator are iterable.

So iterator should know when it will end, Hopefully this code will clear things up:

```
from random import randint

class MyIterator:
  def __init__(self, n):
    self.n = n
    self.i = 0

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.i < self.n:
      self.i += 1
      return randint(1, 10)
    else:
      print("doing cleanup")
      #do the clean up you want
      raise StopIteration()

class MyIterable:
    def __init__(self, n):
      self.n = n
    def __iter__(self):
        return MyIterator(self.n)

for x in MyIterable(5):
  print(x)
```

Output:

```
4
9
7
5
1
doing cleanup
```

**Note:** It is better to do things here using generator function or expression, but this will make things more distinguishable.

Comment: "So iterator should know when it will end" There is nothing wrong or abnormal about an infinite iterator (one that doesn't know when it will end)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, in fact the standard library has an infinite iterators, but mostly you will know when it will end.